# http2 shows http1 in protocol

Tags: nginx, https, http2, lets-encrypt

I've setup https on nginx with "Let's Encrypt" but it's unclear if the http2 is used when accessing the site.

I enable http2 by adding 
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server; 
to the nginx config

When I check the https protocol for the site in Chrome Developer Tools (View -> Developer -> Developer Tools) and reload the page (View -> Reload This Page). Then navigate to the Network tab, click on table header row that starts with Name, right-click on it, and select the Protocol option.

It says http/1.1 instead of h2 for http2.
But for my Google font which is accessed via google.com it says h2
And when checking the domain at https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test it says that the site support http2

When I run
    curl --http2 -I https://example.com/
I get
    curl: (1) Unsupported protocol

So I am a bit confused here.

Do I need to do anything more to make it work with http2?

Here is my complete **NGINX** config file:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

include snippets/ssl-www.example.com.conf;
include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name example.com;

#Password protects the test subdomain
##  auth_basic "Restricted Content";
##  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

location ~ /.well-known {
allow all;
}
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$query_string;
# include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
return 404;
}
# Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
include fastcgi_params;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
#match actual filename with extension or file not found
#try_files $uri $uri =404;
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
}
server {
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
listen 80 default_server;
server_name www.example.com;
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

For your info I followed this tutorial when setting up Let's Encrypt:
digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu 16.04)

I'm testing on Windows 10 latest Chrome

ssllabs.com/ssltest shows:
TLS 1.2     Yes
TLS 1.1     Yes
TLS 1.0     Yes
SSL 3   No
SSL 2   No

Handshake Simulation
IE 11 / Win 10  R       RSA 2048 (SHA256)       TLS 1.2 > h2    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384   ECDH secp384r1  FS

Protocol Details:
SSL 2 handshake compatibility   Yes
HTTP Requests:  (HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
NPN     Yes   h2 http/1.1

Comment: I typically use this chrome extension to tell if a page is http/2 or not. Can you retest with it and see what it says? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http2-and-spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin?hl=en

Comment: Which version of openssl are you using?

Comment: @Faisal Memon The Chrome extension only list google fonts as h2 not my domain.

Comment: @BazzaDP I use OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Comment: Same result in Firefox. When I add Spdy to Firefox it says my domain doesn't support http2.

Comment: What os are you using on the client side?

Comment: Are you sure nginx was built with openssl 1.0.2g? Can you run "nginx -V" and give the output? Also I think your first server block should say "listen 443 ssl http2". I also don't see where you are specifying the ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_keys config  - is this in the snippets files? Can you show this config? Does the site work with https? Any errors when you run https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ on the server? What does it show Chrome 51 / Win 7 section - can you add a screenshot of this section to your question? In fact add all info requested here to your question instead of comments

Comment: @BazzaDP I'm not sure nginx was built with openssl 1.02 but when I do sudo  openssl version, I get: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016. I added more info above and also edited the nginx config a bit to the currently used version.

Comment: @FaisalMemon I'm using Windows 10 latest update.

Comment: Can you give Chrome handshake simulation details? And also give the ALPN setting?

Comment: @BazzaDP Chrome 51 / Win 7  R RSA 2048 (SHA256) TLS 1.2 > h2 ALPN  Yes
NPN  Yes   h2 http/1.1

Comment: Which cipher for Chrome?

Comment: @BazzaDP TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384   ECDH secp384r1  FS This and above are indicated for Win7. I use Windows10 which is not listed as combination with Chrome.

Comment: Everything looks absolutely fine then from server side. Try another computer. Are you perhaps using anti-virus software that intercepts HTTPS connections? Have seen those downgrade you to HTTP/1.1.

Comment: @BazzaDP Hmm, when I browse https://http2.akamai.com with Chrome it says "This browser is not HTTP/2 enabled." Chrome is though up to date Version 56.0.2924.76 (64-bit)... I haven't tested in another computer yet. But with another user account on this laptop it says http2 h2 in Firefox... but still http1 in Chrome. In IE I couldn't find out how to check...

Comment: Still think anti-virus (or some other tool) is doing a MITM meaning you are not directly connecting to the server. Open up https://http2.akamai.com in Chrome, then open Developer tools and look at Security tab and View the certificate. Was it issues by Symantec? Guessing it will be issued by a Avast or some other local CA installed as part of software.

Comment: @BazzaDP Ah issued by Bitdefender...!... :-) It seems you are right...

Comment: Mystery solved! When I disable SLL scanning in Bitdefender my site now shows h2..!.. So the code was correct all the time, just my Antivirus program... Thanks @BassaDP !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why Chrome browser doesn't recognize my http2 server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116072/why-chrome-browser-doesnt-recognize-my-http2-server)

Comment: @BazzaDP Exactly!

Answer (score 0):

for people still looking and havent read through the comments:

try disabling **Bitdefender SSL Scanning** or **Bitdefender Encrypted web scan**

> @BazzaDP Ah issued by Bitdefender...!... :-) It seems you are right...
> –  Gabriel  Jan 29 '17 at 8:54 1

> Mystery solved! When I disable SLL scanning in Bitdefender my site now
> shows h2..!.. So the code was correct all the time, just my Antivirus
> program... Thanks @BassaDP !!! –  Gabriel  Jan 29 '17 at 9:20