# Enable HTTP2 on nginx

Tags: http, nginx, http2

I would like add HTTP2 support to my nginx server. I think all version is good, with **http_v2_module** :

```
nginx version: nginx/1.11.8
built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed'
```

I've edit my vhost and add http2 (**listen 443 ssl http2;**), restart nginx, but no result.

My vhost config :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
  server_name my-domaine.net;
  return 301 https://my-domaine.net$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.my-domaine.net;
  return 301 https://my-domaine.net$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  return 301 https://my-domaine.net$request_uri;
}

server {

  listen 443 ssl http2;

  server_name my-domaine.net;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/app.dev.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/app.dev.error.log;

  ssl_certificate xxx;
  ssl_certificate_key xxx;

  ssl_session_timeout 1h;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:16m;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout 10s;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA
-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE
-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:DES-CBC3-SHA:!RC
4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5:!EXPORT:!EXP:!LOW:!SEED:!CAMELLIA:!IDEA:!PSK:!SRP:!SSLv:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl on;

  # Eviter de se faire piller son site (merci dsfc.net)
  add_header X-Robots-Tag "index,follow,noarchive";
  # HSTS permet de déclarer au client directement dans la réponse HTTP qu'il faut communiquer en HTTPS
  # Cette en-tête permet d'éviter le vol de cookies et le downgrade SSL
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
  # Evite que le contenu soit interprété différemment que définit dans le mime Type
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  # Protection contre le clickjacking
  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
  # Protection contre les failles X-XSS
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
  # Faille spécifique à IE8
  add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
  # Interdire l'embarquement de tout ou partie de votre site dans un site ou logiciel tiers
  add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;

  location / {
    #try_files $uri @prerender;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }

  location ~ ^/(images|fonts)/.*.(png|jpg|svg|jpeg|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot)$ {
    root /opt/app/current/bundle/programs/web.browser/app;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location ~ \.(css|html|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot)$ {
    root /opt/app/current/bundle/programs/web.browser;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }
}
```

If i test the http2 support on [this site](https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test), i see http2 enabled. But on my browser networks, all request are http1 :/

Anyone have idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Nginx compiled with openssl 1.0.2 or above for HTTP/2 to work on Chrome as it now requires the newer ALPN method of negotiating HTTP/2 and 1.0.1 only supports the older NPN method.

See this page for more information: https://www.nginx.com/blog/supporting-http2-google-chrome-users/

Once you fix that, there's another couple of gotchas that can catch you: [why Chrome browser doesn't recognize my http2 server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116072/why-chrome-browser-doesnt-recognize-my-http2-server/41128943#41128943)

Comment: In my case was the antivirus

Answer (score 0):

You missed ip6, try to add it. Please make sure to enable http2 on both ip4 and ip6
(if your server supported ip6)

> **listen [::]:80 http2 ipv6only=on;**