# HTTP/2 enabled but not work at apache2 ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-14.04, http2, ubuntu-server

I do enable HTTP/2 and add to apache virtual hosts "Protocols h2 http/1.1". But when I check http/2 show me this message :
Negative ! Does not support HTTP/2.0.
ALPN is not supported.

Not work. Please help. I use : Ubuntu Server 14.04 , Sentora , apache2

Comment: What is your OpenSSL version ?

Comment: # apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installed: 1.1.0f-2~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+4
  Candidate: 1.1.0f-2~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+4

Comment: i use this and change to 1.0.2 https://www.miguelvallejo.com/updating-to-openssl-1-0-2g-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-14-04-lts-to-stop-cve-2016-0800-drown-attack/  but now not 1.0.2g , now 1.0.2l version. again not work

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have a later openssl installed on your system now, does not mean that Apache was compiled with it.

In your Apache error log you should see something like this on a restart:

```
[Sat Aug 19 00:01:03.004619 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 123:tid 12345678] AH00489: Apache/2.4.27 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.0f configured -- resuming normal operations
```

This shows Apache is running with OpenSSL 1.1.0f. Yours most likely says Openssl 1.0.1. ALPN, which is necessary for HTTP/2 for Chrome and Firefox was only added in OpenSSL 1.0.2.

So you will need to download and recompile Apache with a later version of OpenSSL. I've instructions on [how to enable HTTP/2 on Apache for CentOS/RHEL here on my blog](https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http2/), but this will need to be adapted for Ubuntu.

There are also another couple of gotcha's once you have your server side set up properly:

[why Chrome browser doesn't recognize my http2 server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116072/why-chrome-browser-doesnt-recognize-my-http2-server/41128943#41128943)

Comment: I'm try other server and instal Centos 7 / CWP . Now I can't use ssl with nginx. How can do that ? How can I use centos 7 / CWP with HTTP2 ?

Comment: You've gone from "How can I use HTTP/2 on Ubuntu with Apache" to "How can I use HTTP/2 on Centos 7 /CWP with Nginx". I think it's fair to say that is a completely new question? You've also given zero information as to why it doesn't work. I think you need to understand what StackOverflow is for: to give answers to specific problems for programmers. If you want more general advice, and walk through of how to use your software/infrastructure then I'm sorry but this is not the site for that.

Comment: i try with Ubuntu 14.04 but i can`t do that. And try new VPS. Now i use Centos 7 with CWP. How can i use HTTP2 and NGINX at Centos 7 ???