# http2 doesn't work on nginx 1.12 - debian8

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, http2, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm setting up `http2` on the `nginx`. The below snippet is my nginx virtual host in `sites-available` directory:

```
upstream mysite {
   server unix:/home/user/myproject/mysite.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.mysite.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com.key;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/myproject;
        expires 1d;
    }

#    access_log /opt/simple_academy/logs/nginx-access.log;
#    error_log /opt/simple_academy/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;  # <-
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           proxy_pass http://mysite;
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

The nginx is reverse proxy here and the main webserver is `Gunicorn` that used for serving `Django` codes.
When I test the site with Chrome or Firefox inspect elements, it displays all the connections protocol as `HTTP1.1`. 
How can I solve the problem?

***Updated***
The below is result of `nginx -V` command:

> --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie'

Comment: If you don't proxy, do you get http2?

Comment: add output of `nginx -V` to your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani I updated the question and added result.

Comment: It's not the full results. What version of OpenSSL was it built with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why Chrome browser doesn't recognize my http2 server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116072/why-chrome-browser-doesnt-recognize-my-http2-server)

Comment: I think it would be a SSL version issue as @BazzaDP, pointed out

Comment: Actually Firefox doesn't require ALPN so shouldn't require OpenSSL 1.0.2 or above. But Chrome definitely will.

Comment: How can I find version of Open-ssl that used for?

Comment: You can verify it this way `$ ldd $(which nginx) | grep ssl
 libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0` and 
`$ strings /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 | grep "^OpenSSL"
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`

Comment: I tested my site in `https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test` and it returned `Yeah! mysite.com supports HTTP/2.0. ALPN is not supported.` what do i do now?

Comment: Try and compile latest version of nginx and openssl from source

Comment: I installed it from Nginx official repositories, and my website is online now, I can't compile again :(