# Http2 not functioning

Tags: http2

My websites are https and my hosting company says my server is http2 enabled and functioning correctly. However, when I check my sites they are always utilizing the http1.1 protocol. I have contacted tech support and they say http2 is working and even sent me a screen shot to prove it.

I have tested both of my computers via my home internet and my mobile hotspot on both Firefox and Chrome. I have also tested with my ESET antivirus disabled. It always shows http1.1 via the Network Tab Protocol Column. I also have some site testing tools tell me http2 is function and others say that http2 isn't functioning.

I am looking for a cause-solution and my hosting provider is giving me nothing to work with. They almost act as if they have something to hide.

I am on a shared hosting plan. Apache Version 2.4.33. Anyone have any thoughts?

Additional Details:

I checked 3 http/2 site checking tools and all 3 said my server/website supports http/2.  In addition to Chrome and Firefox Network tabs showing http/1.1, Chrome lighthouse(via DevTools > Audits Tab) says my site is not utilizing http/2.

Via Hosting Tech Support:
There is no load balancer, prefork MPM, and nothing in front of server.

Via `https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest`

ALPN = Yes (h2 http/1.1)
Cipher = This server accepts RC4 cipher, but only with older protocols

Site URL:
https://spinerealignment.com

Comment: You have given us nothing to work with. Which tools say it works and which say it doesn't? Do you have a load balancer, CDN, or anything in front of your server? Is ALPN used? What cipher are you using? Are you using prefork MPM? If you give your site then we can look into it. Otherwise we can only guess...

Comment: See Additional Details posted above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your server supports HTTP/2 fine. You have something in front of your server which is intercepting your connections and down grading them to HTTP/1.1 most likely Anti virus software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why Chrome browser doesn't recognize my http2 server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116072/why-chrome-browser-doesnt-recognize-my-http2-server)