# Why is my site not using http/2 while it is http/2 enabled

Tags: nginx, http2, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a NGINX reverse proxy in front of a website. The NGINX server is http2/ready. If I run a test, all seems good:

[image]

However, when I go to the website using a browser, chrome indicates the website is using http/1.1.

[image]
I can't figure out why. Can anyone help?

Comment: Unsure if you changed something but I see h2 as the protocol for the requests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why Chrome browser doesn't recognize my http2 server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116072/why-chrome-browser-doesnt-recognize-my-http2-server)

Comment: @Shawn C I didn't change a thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why. I enabled the TLS 1.3 protocol on NGINX. Chrome 70 on Win10 handshaked to TLS 1.3 without http/2. As soon as I disabled TLS 1.3 the browser handshaked to TLS1.2 + https/2. The question, of course, is what is faster. I opted for the TLS1.2 + https/2 scenario.