# Cannot use http2 by nginx

Tags: nginx, http2

i am using nginx to serve my application, but i keep fail to use http2 protocol, the following is my nginx version

```
nginx version: nginx/1.17.9
```

openssl version:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

content in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    # run ulimit -n to check
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server_tokens off;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    # Buffer size for post submission
    client_body_buffer_size 10k;
    client_max_body_size 8m;

    # Buffer size for header
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    limit_req_zone $request_uri zone=MYZONE:10m rate=35r/s;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

content in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:

```
 # Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;
    expires $expires;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:40m;
    ssl_session_timeout 4h;
    ssl_session_tickets on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;


    location = /favicon.ico {
      log_not_found off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static_files/;
    }

    location / {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/wsgi.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/wsgi.error_log warn;
        proxy_pass http://app_wsgi:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        limit_req zone=MYZONE burst=15 nodelay;
    }

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://app_wsgi:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        auth_basic "Secure Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

check syntax
nginx -t:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

after start nginx and then i do the curl command for https and https:

curl -I --http2 0.0.0.0:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 10:20:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://0.0.0.0/
```

curl -I --http2 --cacert certs/server.crt https://0.0.0.0

```
HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx
date: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 10:15:20 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 13376
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
vary: Cookie, Accept-Encoding
set-cookie: csrftoken=dYCEOQQh70PqCXiyuylGoGS83GEWgU5omH33KnSr2XSziyXNbFoOepKlAprzoA0G; expires=Sat, 24 Apr 2021 10:15:20 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
```

it shows http2 successfully, but i browse web page to https://0.0.0.0, and i check the dev console, i found all the requests all still using http/1.1 protocol. I also go to nginx server to check access.log, and there are also all http/1.1 request logs. there is no error in error log.

i have already tried to search and try for it for very long hours, i still cannot get it to serve by protocol http2. please help me and thank you very much!

Update:
cert and security tab from chrome:
[image]

[image]

Comment: no one has idea?

Comment: Do you have anti-virus software installed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116072/why-chrome-browser-doesnt-recognize-my-http2-server?rq=1

Comment: hi @BarryPollard , thank you for your hint, but i think it is not the problem from anti-virus software, because i can see some website their protocol is https in dev tool

Comment: And who’s the certificate issued? Anti-virus can still intercept HTTPS connections (and downgrade them from HTTP/2 to HTTP/1.1).

Comment: i use self-signed cert to test now, or is it because self-signed? i haven't bought a formal cert

Comment: No that shouldn’t cause an issue. Can you add a screenshot of the Security tab in Chrome developer tools to your question and also check the Certificate issuer according to Chrome.

Comment: Hi, @Barry Pollard , sorry for lare reply, i added the images to my question

Comment: Have you tried to cURL the server and see the full reply?

Comment: yes @JuanSebastian , i tried it and it says http/2, the result is posted in my question

Comment: is it because chrome doesnt trust my cert? so if i use a trusted CA then this problem can be solved?

Comment: No it’s because the cert is issued by Avast because you have anti-virus software installed. It is replacing your actual self-signed cert and also downgrading you’re connection. Turn off Avast and you will get HTTP/2.

Comment: @Barry Pollard , oh yeah yeah it really works, i am very thankful to you ! thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why Chrome browser doesn't recognize my http2 server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116072/why-chrome-browser-doesnt-recognize-my-http2-server)

Comment: yes sir , i vote already