# Debugging HTTP/2 with curl gives different responses from different places

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, curl, http2

**Context**

I try to enable `HTTP/2` through my nginx configurations:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name stg.grozissaviems.lt;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/stg.grozissaviems.lt.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/stg.grozissaviems.lt.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
}
```

**Issue**

When I run `curl -I -L https://stg.grozissaviems.lt` to debug `HTTP/2`:

- through my laptop terminal (MacOS) I see

  ```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: nginx/1.21.1
    Date: Mon, 26 Sep 2022 08:11:07 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Connection: keep-alive
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.23
    Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private
    pragma: no-cache
    Expires: Mon, 26 Sep 2022 08:11:07 GMT
    Link: </build/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf>; rel="preload"; as="font",</build/fonts/Quicksand-Light.ttf>; rel="preload"; as="font",</build/fonts/Quicksand-Medium.ttf>; rel="preload"; as="font",</build/fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf>; rel="preload"; as="font",</build/fonts/Quicksand-SemiBold.ttf>; rel="preload"; as="font"
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  ```
- through my VPS terminal (Ubuntu) I see

  ```
    HTTP/2 200
    server: nginx/1.21.1
    date: Mon, 26 Sep 2022 08:11:36 GMT
    content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    vary: Accept-Encoding
    x-powered-by: PHP/8.0.23
    cache-control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private
    pragma: no-cache
    expires: Mon, 26 Sep 2022 08:11:36 GMT
    link: </build/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf>; rel="preload"; as="font",</build/fonts/Quicksand-Light.ttf>; rel="preload"; as="font",</build/fonts/Quicksand-Medium.ttf>; rel="preload"; as="font",</build/fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf>; rel="preload"; as="font",</build/fonts/Quicksand-SemiBold.ttf>; rel="preload"; as="font"
    strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
  ```

When I debug it using [this KeyCDN tool](https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test) I see:

> HTTP/2 protocol is supported.
>
> ALPN extension is supported.

When I access the website using Google Chrome, in the Network tab I see:

> stg.grozissaviems.lt  200  http/1.1
>
> Quicksand-Bold.ttf    200  http/1.1

Why does it differ?

Comment: @Rob oops sorry, deleted the images, updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the issue. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41128943/2333299):

> You are using anti-virus software and it is MITM your traffic and so
> downgrading you to HTTP/1.1. ...

I did turn my anti-virus off and I could finally see `HTTP/2` in the Networks tab!

In case someone stumbles upon my question and turning anti-virus software does not help, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41128943/2333299) for more solutions.